# Powershell variable properties not passed after "if" condition

Tags: powershell

When I run:

```
PS H:\> $txtfiles = gci "C:\temp" -filter *.txt
PS H:\> $txtfiles.Fullname
```

I get:

```
C:\temp\GPOList.txt
C:\temp\test.txt
```

I'd expect the same result if I want to add a condition afterwards:

```
$txtfiles = gci "C:\temp" -filter *.txt ; if ($txtfiles) {"blah `n $txtfiles.FullName" }
```

Instead I get:

```
blah
GPOList.txt test.txt.FullName
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need [`$(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#subexpression-operator--) in order to properly interpolate the value of `.FullName` inside your expandable string `"..."` otherwise what you're doing is coercing `$FullName` to string and appending the word "FullName" at the end. You need to also convert that array of 2 values into a string joined by new line characters **before** interpolating, otherwise it will get joined by [`$OFS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.3#ofs) (by default a space character) when coerced.

A simple example:

```bash
$array = @(
    'foo'
    'bar'
    'baz'
)
"[$array]"
# [foo bar baz]

"[$($array -join [Environment]::NewLine)]"
# [foo
# bar
# baz]
```

In summary, applied to your code:

```bash
$txtfiles = [pscustomobject]@{
    FullName = @(
        'C:\temp\GPOList.txt'
        'C:\temp\test.txt'
    )
}

"blah `n$($txtfiles.FullName -join [Environment]::NewLine)"
# blah 
# C:\temp\GPOList.txt
# C:\temp\test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, thanks. I also got the property when seperating the script block

```
{"blah `n $txtfiles.FullName" }
```

to

```
{"blah `n" ; $txtfiles.FullName}
```